# How to edit wordpress RSS feed to show post title only

Tags: posts, customization

Hi everyone can someone help me on how to edit WordPress rss feed to show only title of the post, i use android application that display notification as rss feed that's why i want to show only a title of the post. OR another way if you guys can show me how to edit that rss feed to show both title and post description the one i add in yoast description box i will very very much appreciate.

Thank you all for you time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the codex:

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

Google also gave me this **`https://konstantin.blog/2011/wordpress-posts-without-titles-in-rss-feeds/`** – the comments of the blog is most informative.